# Programmatically fetching current Add-In version using ArcGIS Pro SDK

Tags: c#, arcgis-pro-sdk

The version of a custom ArcGIS Pro SDK Add-In is held in the config.daml of the Add-In project:

```
<AddInInfo id="{some guid}" version="1.0" desktopVersion="1.1.3068">
```

How do I programmatically access the current version of the Add-In  (**without** reading the xml file directly at runtime using an xmlreader)?

In the Add-In framework for ArcMap using ArcObjects SDK, the Add-In version could be accessed like so:

```
My.ThisAddIn.Version
```

Has anyone discovered the ArcGIS Pro SDK way of doing this? I would imagine it's possible but can't find the method or property to retrieve it.

I guess the version number is also held in AssemblyInfo.cs, but i'd rather use the value from config.daml.

Comment: Could you use the `System.Reflection` namespace?

Comment: @Branco I think this way will only retrieve the assembly version from assemblyinfo, which isn't really what I want (could be different from addin version).

Comment: Maybe I haven't used add-ins enough, but I thought they were tied together.  Past that, I am not sure.  Did you cross post at GeoNet in case one of their engineers are surfing the forums?

Comment: @Branco I believe it's possible to have different versions for your addin and your assembly, I'll check. And yeah - i'll get this posted on geonet.

Answer (score 3):

It's too late. Still, I'm sharing this for newbies who still need help with this.

```csharp
  var addInInfo = FrameworkApplication.GetAddInInfos().First(addIn => addIn.Name == "your addin name");
  var version = addInInfo.Version;
```